# Changing the highlighted row of tabularray in beamer

Tags: beamer, tabularray

I want the color of the row to change in slide 2 only, how is it possible with tabularray, I tried to use `\only<4>{row{2} = {blue!30},}`, but it didn't work

I also used `\alt<1>{\SetRow{background}{blue!30}}{}`

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{
every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
every node/.style={
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=base,
 minimum width=1.8cm,
 align=center,
 text depth=.25ex,
 outer sep=1.5pt},
every path/.style={
  thick, 
  rounded corners
  }
}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    

  \begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|m{0.1\textwidth}|   
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}|
              m{0.1\textwidth}|    
              m{0.25\textwidth}| 
  },
  \only<4>{row{2} = {Gold!30},}
}  
\hline \hline 
x  & y &z & e & d & f\\ \hline \hline  
x  & y &z & e & d & f\\ \hline \hline 
x  & y &z & e & d & f\\ \hline \hline 
x  & y &z & e & d & f\\ \hline \hline 
x  & y &z & e & d & f\tikzmark{a}\\ \hline \hline   
\end{tblr}
\pause
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [right=2cm,above=2cm,minimum width=0pt] at (pic cs:a) (A) {A};
  \draw [<-,out=5,in=180] ([xshift=15pt]{pic cs:a}) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the library `functional` and create a command that you can use inside the `tblr` environment to set the row color (see section 5.5 in the current [`tabularray` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\prgNewFunction\styleRowOnly{mmm}{
 \only<#1>{\rowSetStyle{#2}{#3}}
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style={
  remember picture, 
  baseline
},
every node/.style={
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=base,
  minimum width=1.8cm,
  align=center,
  text depth=.25ex,
  outer sep=1.5pt},
  every path/.style={
    thick, 
    rounded corners
  }
}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|m{0.1\textwidth}|   
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}|
              m{0.1\textwidth}|    
              m{0.25\textwidth}| 
  },
  process=\styleRowOnly{4}{2}{blue!30},
}  
\hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline  
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f\tikzmark{a} \\ \hline \hline   
\end{tblr}
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[right=2cm, above=2cm, minimum width=0pt] at (pic cs:a) (A) {A};
  \draw[<-, out=5, in=180] ([xshift=15pt]{pic cs:a}) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another, maybe simpler, solution could be to use a custom color for row two which you change just on the relevant frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style={
  remember picture, 
  baseline
},
every node/.style={
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=base,
  minimum width=1.8cm,
  align=center,
  text depth=.25ex,
  outer sep=1.5pt},
  every path/.style={
    thick, 
    rounded corners
  }
}  

\begin{document}
\colorlet{rowiicolor}{transparent!0}
\begin{frame}
\only<4>{\colorlet{rowiicolor}{blue!30}}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|m{0.1\textwidth}|   
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}|
              m{0.1\textwidth}|    
              m{0.25\textwidth}| 
  },
  row{2} = {rowiicolor},
}  
\hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline  
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f\tikzmark{a} \\ \hline \hline   
\end{tblr}
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[right=2cm, above=2cm, minimum width=0pt] at (pic cs:a) (A) {A};
  \draw[<-, out=5, in=180] ([xshift=15pt]{pic cs:a}) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output would be the same as above.

---

If you want to color different columns and rows on different slides, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\prgNewFunction\styleRowOnly{mmm}{
 \only<#1>{\rowSetStyle{#2}{#3}}
}
\prgNewFunction\styleColOnly{mmm}{
 \only<#1>{\columnSetStyle{#2}{#3}}
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{
every picture/.style={
  remember picture, 
  baseline
},
every node/.style={
  inner sep=0pt,
  anchor=base,
  minimum width=1.8cm,
  align=center,
  text depth=.25ex,
  outer sep=1.5pt},
  every path/.style={
    thick, 
    rounded corners
  }
}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|m{0.1\textwidth}|   
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}| 
              m{0.1\textwidth}|
              m{0.1\textwidth}|    
              m{0.25\textwidth}| 
  },
  process={
    \styleRowOnly{2}{2}{green!30}
    \styleRowOnly{3}{5}{blue!30}
    \styleColOnly{4}{4}{red!30}
  },
}  
\hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline  
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f \\ \hline \hline 
x & y & z & e & d & f\tikzmark{a} \\ \hline \hline   
\end{tblr}
\pause
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[right=2cm, above=2cm, minimum width=0pt] at (pic cs:a) (A) {A};
  \draw[<-, out=5, in=180] ([xshift=15pt]{pic cs:a}) to (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The simpler approach fails here, as you would always override the color of one cell with `transparent!0` which would leave an ugly gap.

Comment: Thank you so much, what if I want to change the colored row, one slide row 2 will be blue, then the following slide col 2 will be blue and so on

Comment: @Diana I added a variation of my answer. The simpler approach cannot easily be applied here, because you would always override the color of some of the cells.